# jquery check values before submit

Tags: jquery

i have a page with a link , when use clicks the link a new select tag will be appeared , then when the user submit the form i want to ensure that the user select an option for each select tag

you can go to the last jquery function , but i put some codes of creating the select tags

## html

```
<div class="container" id="addCell">
    <form id="acForm"method="POST" action="<?php echo URL; ?>Cell/addCell">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name"class="longInput1"/>
                <p>
                <p>
                    <label>City</label>
                    <select id="countrySelector" name="city">
                    </select>
                </p>
            </li>
            <li id="intersectionCells">
                <p>
                    <label>Inserted cells</label>
                    <a href="#" class="smallLink" id="acaclink">new</a>
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" class="button1" value="save"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

## jquery

```
$("#addCell").ready(function(){
    $("#addCell").on('click',"#acaclink",function(){
        var me = this;
        var cityName = $("#countrySelector").val();
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Cell/getCellsInCity/"+cityName+"/TRUE",function(data){
            var options = '';
            options+="<option>Select Cell</option>";
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                options += "<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
            }
            $(me).closest('li').append('<p>\n\
            <label>Select Cell</label>\n\
            <select name="acSelect[]">\n\
             '+options+'\n\
</select>\n\
<a href="#" class="removeA">delete</a>\n\
<span class="errorMessage"></span>\n\
</p>');
        });
    });
});
$("#addCell").ready(function(){
    $("#addCell").on('click',".removeA",function (){
        $(this).closest('p').remove();
    });
});
$("#addCell").ready(function (){
    $("#countrySelector").change(function (){
        var cityName = $("#countrySelector").val();
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Cell/getCellsInCity/"+cityName+"/TRUE",function(data){
            var options = '';
            options+="<option>Select Cell</option>";
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                options += "<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
            }
            $("#intersectionCells select").html(options);
        });
    });
});
```

and this is the form validation

```
$("#addCell").ready(function (){
    $("#acForm").on('submit',function (){
        var errorCount = 0;
        $('span.errorMessage').text('');
        $('#intersectionCells select').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.val() === 'Select Cell'){
                var error = 'Please select a cell' ; // take the input field from label
                $this.next('span').text(error);
                errorCount = errorCount + 1;   
            }
        });
        if(errorCount==0){
            $(this)[0].submit(); // submit form if no error
        }
    });
});
```

but the spam doesn't appear as i want

Comment: why you use `$('#addCell').ready()`?

Comment: @thecodeparadox i always begin with that , i am new to jquery so i always do the same way as i learned

Comment: is it wrong ? but i tried to alter error var and it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ujrNu/

After this

```
if(errorCount==0){
            $(this)[0].submit(); // submit form if no error
        }
```

you should add:

```
else{
   return false;
}
```

otherwise your form will get posted anyway.

The second problem is this line:

```
$this.next('span').text(error);
```

next returns the NEXT sibling, not the next sibling that is a span. If the next sibling is NOT a span, it will return null. In your case, the next sibling isn't a span, it's an A tag. So you want this:

```
$this.siblings('span :first').text(error);
```

Comment: when i make return false , the form didn't posted , and that is good , but the error message didn't appear   ( i know in ur jsfiddle it appears :( )

Answer (score 3):

you should not use `ready` for document elements, use `$(document).ready(function(){...})` and you can use `preventDefault()` if form has errors to prevent it from getting submitted:

```
$("#acForm").on('submit',function (e){
    var errorCount = 0;
    $('span.errorMessage').text('');
    $('#intersectionCells select').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val() == 'Select Cell'){
            var error = 'Please select a cell' ;
            $this.next('span').text(error);
            errorCount++;   
        }
    });

    if (errorCount > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: your code make the form doesn't submit if it has error , but the message error doesn't appear

Comment: @William Kinaan so the problem is in the markup, the `span` tag,             `$this.next('span').text(error);` make sure that the `span` is added to the DOM before handling `submit`.

Comment: yes you are right , with span ,and i changed it to $this.siblings('span :first').text(error);

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#acForm").on('submit',function (e){
        var errorCount = 0;
        $('span.errorMessage').text('');
        $('#intersectionCells select').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.val() === 'Select Cell'){
                var error = 'Please select a cell' ; // take the input field from label
                $this.next('span').text(error);
                errorCount = errorCount + 1;   
            }
        });
        if(errorCount==0){
            $(this)[0].submit(); // submit form if no error
        }
        e.preventDefault(); // this will stop the form submit
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/Cc3dH/1/)**

Comment: still submiting the page without checking

Comment: i had to change the nest span with $this.siblings('span :first').text(error); really thank you for helping me