# check before submit form

Tags: php, jquery

how to check form before submit.

i want to inputs have any data when user is typing into input or checked checkbox.

i cant use jquery for check and manage submit form, after submit page is refresh and that empty input and etc.

**for example:**

```
$('form#myForm1').submit(function(){ ... })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery.validate plugin to add validation rules on your from such as:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    rules:
    {
        field1:
            {
                required: true              
            }

    },
    messages:
    {
        field1:
            {
                required: "<span class="error">Enter field1.</span>"                
            }
    }
});
```

Check for more information at [jquery form validation](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/2/10/An-Introduction-to-jQuery-and-Form-Validation-2)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use server side check, clientside check can make it possible to manipulate the data and send any data...

For your question, you can use a plugin for validation of fields...
Example:

```
$('#buy').submit(function() {
      if ($('#productSize').val().length < 1) {
            $('#error').html('My Error Message').show();
            return false;
      }
});
```

Example from: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/checking-form-value-before-submit

Example stackoverflow: [jquery check values before submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646264/jquery-check-values-before-submit)

Answer (score 1):

simply use

```
< form onsubmit="return javascriptFunciton();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [HTML5 Form Validation](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/#.UTWnoDDNjC8). However as the validation is on the user's side you should always validate the data on the server side as well. It's fairly easy to go around any user-sided validation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can check to make sure the inputs are filled!

1- Using jquery you could do something like that:

```
if(!$(#"input1").val()){do some thing}
```

2- Using Javascript you could do something like that:

```
if(document.getElementById("input1").value==""){do some thing}
```

3- Using some HTML5 attributes like: "required" that makes an input field required to be filled out.

But yet, the best way is using PHP's perfect input validation and security functions  for controlling  the users' data.